# Método sort para ordenar el ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, array, ordenamiento

Tengo declarada una dinámica de enteros en Java, es decir:

```
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

... y a esta le voy agregando números.

```
lista.add(5); lista.add(7); lista.add(3);
```

Lo que quiero es ordenar esa lista, y que quede así, `3, 5, 7`, y para eso, traté de usar un método llamado `sort`, de la siguiente manera.

```
lista.sort();
```

Pero me pide un argumento que no conozco. Quisiera ordenarlo de menor a mayor, aunque si puedo ordenarlo de mayor a menor, no importa, porque luego puedo dar vuelta la lista.

El error que tengo es:

> The method sort(Comparator<? super Integer>) in the type ArrayList<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments ()

¿Cómo hago para aplicar ese método sort a la lista?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Antes de Java 8 puedes llamar el `.sort()` de esta manera:

```
lista.sort(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
```

[**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/VZIVN53165).

A partir de Java 8, puedes simplificar la llamada usando una expresión lambda:

```
lista.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));
```

[**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/DGC11149).

O también puedes usar la respuesta propuesta por @Error404.

Answer (score 16):

Podrás hacerlo importando la clase [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html):

```
import java.util.Collections;
```

Y usando el método `sort` de la siguiente manera:

```
Collections.sort(lista);
```

Por lo que tu ejemplo completo quedaría:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class OrdenaNumeros
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lista.add(5); 
    lista.add(7); 
    lista.add(3);

    Collections.sort(lista);

    for (Integer numero: lista) {
        System.out.println(numero);
    }   

  }
}
```

Lo que te daría la siguiente salida:

```
3
5
7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lista.add(5);
lista.add(7);
lista.add(3);

Collections.sort(lista, Integer::compareTo);
for (Integer in : lista) {
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class OrdenaNumeros
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    lista.add("RE00998"); 
    lista.add("RE00999"); 
    lista.add("REA1000");
    lista.add("REA1001");

    Collections.sort(lista);

    for (String datos: lista) {
        System.out.println(datos);
    }   

  }
}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar una explicación de cómo funciona el código que colocaste para el problema que plantea el op?

Comment: La primera respuesta está en inglés, sugiero eliminar una de las dos respuestas y complementarla. Además traducirla al español.