# Ordenar List alfabéticamente

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo ordenar un list de la siguiente forma, si tengo esto:

```
public Owner(String name, int id, boolean priv) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.priv = priv;
}
```

y por otra banda esta función:

```
    List<Owner> owners;

    for (Home h : this.inf.keySet()) {
        owners = this.inf.get(h);

        for (Owner ow : owners) {
            output.write(ow.getName());
            output.newLine();
            output.write(Integer.toString(p.getId()));
            output.newLine();
            output.write(Boolean.toString(p.isPriv()));
            output.newLine();
        }
    }
    output.close();
}
```

Simplemente me escribe los Owners de cada Home, aunque me salto bastante código, los Owners están en un list y éste me los escribe tal cual han sido introducidos.

Me gustaría que me diera los Owners en orden alfabético, sin tocar el list (es decir tiene que ser un list sí o sí), ¿cómo debería hacerlo?

¿Un comparador quizá, que compare los nombres? y ¿Qué debería poner en el comparado?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, intentamos evitar duplicados, así que intenta buscar las preguntas ya hechas y respondidas a ver si responden tu pregunta (una simple búsqueda de "java ordenar" devuelve preguntas como: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36804/m%c3%a9todo-sort-para-ordenar-el-arraylist-en-java). Si no encuentras respuesta, indica cuáles son los problemas que tienes con las respuestas existentes.

Answer (score 3):

Para ordernar una lista podes usar `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`.

En tu caso el nombre del owner es un string así que el comparator es bastante trivial:

(Asumamos que la clase Owner tiene un getName() que devuelve el nombre del owner como string)

```
Comparator<Owner> comparator = new Comparator<>(){
    int compare(Owner object1, Owner object2){
         //Como string tiene ya un comparator definido
         return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para ordenar una lista puedes usar la clase utility Collections que tiene un metodo que es el sort que te lo va a ordenar, te dejo la documentacion oficial

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-

Ese metodo requiere implementas la interfaz Comparable y redefinir el metodo compareTo y ya en la deficion del compareTo indicas el parametro de ordenacion

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Ejemplo de codigo

> public class Owner implements Comparable{
>
> //Creas el constructor y sus atributos
>
> //Implementas el metodo para que ordene por el nombre
>
> public int compareTo(Owern a){
>
> return this.name.compareTo(a.name);
>
> }
>
> }

Y ya en el main importas Collections y haces

> Collections.sort(nombreDeLaLista);