# Ordenar un ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

agradecería si alguien puede ayudarme con esto,
Tengo una clase Jugador que tiene los atributos nombre, edad y partidasGanadas,
esa clase Jugador, lo tengo ingresado en un ArrayList listaJugadores donde estan todos los jugadores que se van ingresando.
Como hago para ordenar el ArrayList listaJugadores con criterio de las partidas ganadas?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, para ordenar metodos en java existe un post el cual te añadire en el siguiente [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36804/m%C3%A9todo-sort-para-ordenar-el-arraylist-en-java)
además me tome la libertad de editar la pregunta ya que "ordenacion" no es una palabra aceptada por la RAE.

en caso de  que el primer link no respondiera tus dudas adjunto un segundo link en como usar sort en [java](https://www.discoduroderoer.es/formas-de-ordenar-un-arraylist/)

en caso de que el primer y segundo link no te sirvieran para aprender a usar el metodo sort en java adjunto un [TERCER](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2014/09/como-ordenar-arrays-en-java.html) link .

como usar sort en java:

```
 Arrays.Sort(), Collections.reverseOrder()
```

Para ordenar arrays de cualquier tipo Java dispone del método sort de la clase Arrays.

Para utilizarlo es necesario incluir el import:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Por ejemplo, dado el siguiente array de Strings:

```
String [] nombres = {"juan", "pedro", "ana", "maria", "felipe", "luis", "eduardo"};
```

para ordenarlo de forma ascendente escribiremos la instrucción:
Arrays.sort(nombres);

Si mostramos el array por pantalla, comprobaremos que está ordenado de forma ascendente:

```
for(String s : nombres)

      System.out.println(s);
```

Arrays.sort ordena de forma ascendente (de menor a mayor). Para ordenar un array de forma descendente (de mayor a menor) hay que indicarlo utilizando el método reverseOrder() de la clase Collections.

Para utilizar reverseOrder es necesario incluir el import:

```
import java.util.Collections;
```

Por ejemplo, para ordenar el array nombres de forma descendente escribimos la instrucción Arrays.sort de la siguiente forma:

```
Arrays.sort(nombres, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

También tenemos la opción de ordenar solo una parte del array, indicando la posición del elemento inicial y la del elemento final (que no se incluye en la ordenación).

Por ejemplo, para ordenar solo los elementos 1, 2 y 3 ("pedro", "ana", "maria") del array nombres escribimos la instrucción de esta forma:
Arrays.sort(nombres, 1, 4);

El 1 indica la posición del elemento donde comienza la ordenación y el 4 indica la posición del primer elemento que no entra en la ordenación.
El contenido del array después de esta ordenación es el siguiente:

```
juan
ana
maria
pedro
felipe
luis
eduardo

vemos que solo se han ordenado los elementos 1, 2 y 3. El resto quedan igual:
También podemos ordenar solo una parte del array en orden inverso. Por ejemplo, para ordenar solo los elementos 1, 2 y 3 en orden inverso:

Arrays.sort(nombres, 1,4, Collections.reverseOrder());

El contenido del array es ahora:

juan
pedro
maria
ana
felipe
luis
eduardo
```

Con Arrays.sort podemos ordenar arrays de cualquier tipo de datos.
 Por ejemplo, para ordenar un array de enteros:

```
int [] numeros = {3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 7, 0, -1};
Arrays.sort(numeros);
```

//mostrarlo ordenado

```
for (int n : numeros) {
       System.out.println(n);
}

Collections.reverOrder()
```

solo funciona para arrays de objetos.

Por este motivo si queremos ordenar de forma descendente arrays de tipos de datos simples debemos utilizar la clase envolvente equivalente al tipo de dato básico.
 Puedes ver las clases envolventes que corresponden a cada tipo de dato en esta entrada.

Por ejemplo, para ordenar un array de enteros forma descendente hay que declararlo de tipo Integer en lugar de int.

```
   Integer [] numeros = {3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 7, 0, -1};

Arrays.sort(numeros, Collections.reverseOrder());

for (int n : numeros) {
       System.out.println(n);
}
```

espero servirte de ayuda,sinceramente

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo debes escoger un método de ordenamiento, te haré la explicación usando el método de búrbuja:

```
public static void BurbujaColObj(ArrayList<Jugador> jugador) {       
    Jugador aux;
    for(int i = 0;i < jugador.size()-1;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < jugador.size()-i-1;j++){
            // El if de abajo va a determinar si el primero es menor que el segundo
            // y si es true, se va a realizar el swap con una variable aux para
            // mover los objetos del array
            if(jugador.get(j+1).getpartidasGanadas() <  jugador.get(j).getpartidasGanadas()){    
                aux = jugador.get(j+1);
                jugador.set(j+1,jugador.get(j));
                jugador.set(j,aux);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

La implementación anterior es la del método de burbuja para colecciones de objetos, hay distintas maneras de aplicar este método pero en lo personal esta es la que yo utilizo.

Con ese método se está ordenando el array en orden ascendente, es decir; desde  el que menos partidas ganadas tiene, hasta el que más tiene.