# Ordenar lista de listas en Java

Tags: java, lista

Tengo una lista de listas, cada sublista en su primera y segunda posición tiene un número entero, algo de la siguiente manera:

```
Lista: [[12, 4] , [4, 4] , [7, 3] , [ 6, 2]]
```

¿Hay alguna forma de poder ordenar dicha lista de sublistas por el primer número en JAVA? En otras palabras, hacer que se pueda ver como:

```
Lista: [[4 , 4] , [6 , 2] , [7 , 3] , [12 , 4]]
```

Para ordenar una lista normalmente se usa `.sort()`, pero con una lista de listas no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de la misma manera, usando [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)). Simplemente tienes que aportar un comparador para tu caso específico.

```
 listaDeListas.sort((List<Integer> a ,List<Integer> b) -> a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0)));
```

El definir el tipo de a y b es opcional, se podría poner simplemente

```
 listaDeListas.sort((a, b) -> a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0)));
```

Comment: Solo para confirmar, 'a' sería mi primer elemento y 'b' el segundo de la sublista verdad?

Comment: @Bar Hector No, `a` y `b` son dos elementos cualesquiera de la lista "padre" que quieras comparar, por lo que son dos sublistas cualesquiera. Lo que hay a la derecha es cómo comparar esas dos sublistas, que en tu caso es comparando el primer elemento de cada una.

Comment: No comprendo eso de dos elementos cualesquiera. ¿Son los nombres de las variables o cómo?

Comment: Puedes encontrar más información aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36804/m%c3%a9todo-sort-para-ordenar-el-arraylist-en-java

Comment: @BarHector cuando haces `sort` en una lista, tienes que pasarle un `Comparator`, un objeto que sirve para definir cómo dos objetos del mismo tipo (dos objetos de la lista) se comparan. En tu caso, tú quieres ordenar una lista de listas, por lo que tu comparator ha de comparar dos "sublistas". Está implementado como una función lambda, sobre la cual puedes leer más en google o en este mismo sitio.

Comment: Gracias.
En el caso de LinkedList y no ArrayList ¿cambia mucho el código?

Comment: @BarHector Absolutamente nada. Es lo bueno de programar contra una interfaz (`List`). Tienes la garantía de que todas sus implementaciones (como son `LinkedList` y `ArrayList`) funcionarán mientras uses su API

Answer (score 3):

Como la pregunta no es específica para Java 8 o superiores, incluyo la aproximación tradicional.

No sé si te refieres al método sort de la clase `Collections`, pero dicha clase sobrecarga ese método permitiendo que se le pase un parámetro adicional, un `Comparator`. En dicho `Comparator` puedes definir la comparación que tú quieras.

Del javadoc de Collections:

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>  void  sort(List<T> list)
Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements. 

static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the specified comparator.
```

¿Cómo implementar un `Comparator` como clase anónima?

```
Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {

                Integer primerElemento1 = o1.get(0);
                Integer primerElemento2 = o2.get(0);
                return primerElemento1.compareTo(primerElemento2);
            }
});
```

También podemos emplear directamente el método sort con un argumento definido en la clase List

```
 lista.sort(new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {

                Integer primerElemento1 = o1.get(0);
                Integer primerElemento2 = o2.get(0);
                return primerElemento1.compareTo(primerElemento2);
            }
});
```

Al ser Comparator un interfaz funcional, puede ser reemplazado por una expresión lambda en Java 8 y superiores, que es la solución propuesta por Pablo Lozano. Os pego aquí mi solución empleando su misma nomenclatura y la suya para que comparéis y constatéis que es exactamente lo mismo, pero escrito de una forma simplificada. Ya depende de qué versión de Java os permitan u os resulte más fácil de entender.

```
lista.sort(new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
                return a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0));
            }
     });

lista.sort((List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) -> a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0)));
lista.sort((a, b) -> a.get(0).compareTo(b.get(0)));
```

Cierro con un ejemplo mínimo

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class TestSortList {

    public static String imprimeLista(List lista) {
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        sb.append("[");
        
        for (Object element : lista) {
        
            if (element instanceof List) {
                sb.append(imprimeLista((List) element));
            } else {
                sb.append(element.toString());
            }
            
            sb.append(",");
        }
        
        if (sb.length() > 1) {
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1); // Elimina última coma
        }
        
        sb.append("]");
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<List<Integer>> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        
        lista.add(Arrays.asList(12, 4));
        lista.add(Arrays.asList(4, 4));
        lista.add(Arrays.asList(7, 3));
        lista.add(Arrays.asList(6, 2));
        
        Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
                
                Integer primerElemento1 = o1.get(0);
                Integer primerElemento2 = o2.get(0);
                return primerElemento1.compareTo(primerElemento2);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(imprimeLista(lista));
    }

}
```

Comment: Cuando el profesor te pide un trabajo y te da longitud mínima pero no máxima... +1 por el tocho (por la explicación detallada, digo... )

Comment: @Benito-B Gracias por apreciarlo! :-)

Comment: Gracias.
En el caso de usar LinkedList y no ArrayList ¿Qué tanto cambia el código?

Comment: @BarHector Pues prácticamente nada. Tanto ArrayList como LinkedList implementan el interfaz List. En mi ejemplo solo tendrías que cambiar la instanciación de la lista y poner List<List<Integer>> lista = new LinkedList<>();. El resto sería exactamente igual.

Comment: @BarHector Lo mismo aplica a la solución de Pablo. Como digo, son EXACTAMENTE los mismos conceptos y métodos, solo que expresados de forma distinta.